# this.id is empty for asp:CheckBox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, checkbox

I have an `asp:CheckBox` with the following tag:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest1" runat="server" onchange="cbChange(this.id);"/>
```

`cbChange` is a Javascript function in the `<head>` that looks like this (it's simple for now):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function cbChange(senderID) {
        alert('|' + senderID + '|'); // '|' is to help see string length
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Now, whenever I click on `cbTest1`, I get the alert box with the following text:

> ||

In other words, it's an empty/null string. I should also note that when I use a more traditional `<input>` that I get the expected results:

(Code for `<input>`)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cbtest2" id="cbtest2" onchange="cbChange(this.id);" />
```

(Text in alert box when I check `cbtest2`)

> |cbtest2|

Why would I be getting the null/empty string with the `asp:Checkbox`, but expected behaviour with the `<input>`?

**EDIT** I did a little bit more research, since the `asp:CheckBox` has the `ID` attribute instead of (lowercase) `id`, so I tried `onchange="cbChange(this.ID);"`. Now I get the following output in the alert box:

> |undefined|

Why would this also be happening?

Comment: take a look at html source of the page in the browser and search for "cbTest" - what element has it as [part of] its `id` attribute value?

Comment: `ID` is a server-side property of a `Control` - it contributes to client-side `id` attribute, but does not exist on the client, that's why you get `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pull up your rendered page source, you'll see the ASP actually renders this as:

```
<span onchange="cbChange(this.id);"><input id="ContentArea_cbTest" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentArea$cbTest" /></span>
```

Your `input` element is actually nested with a `span` element.

Using Pure JS, you can still get the ID of your `input` by doing:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest" runat="server" onchange="cbChange(this.childNodes[0].id);"/>
```

Comment: I did just notice that thanks to @Igor. So is it trying to get the id of the `span` instead? And since the span has no id, I'm guessing that's why the output isn't what I expect

Comment: Yup, exactly why. I've updated my answer and included the code to get the ID of the child input.

Comment: thanks, that works nicely. I can now get the expected id. It is strange that the `onchange` method gets put into the `span` though

Answer (score 1):

If you view source, you'll see:

```
<span onchange="cbChange(this.id);">
    <input id="cbTest" type="checkbox" name="cbTest" />
</span>
```

One of the downsides of WebForms - the markup doesn't always come as you'd expect.

Your best bet is to hook up the event manually on the client. If you happen to be using jQuery, you can do:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#<%= cbTest.ClientID %>").click(function() {
        cbChange(jQuery(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

(If you're not using jQuery, do the same thing, just hook up to the click event manually using regular javascript - I always have to look up that syntax though...)

Comment: I think what I'll end up doing is just use an `input` instead, but thank you for the help

Comment: @Joe -- `this.childNodes[0].id` should do the trick for Pure JS :)

Comment: @tymeJV Getting the id isn't an issue, it's the event. I believe `document.getElementById("someid").onclick = function () { alert(this.id); };` works for all browsers, but I think there's a "more correct" way. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6348597/111266) shows why I just use jQuery so I don't have to think about it.